# How do you set row selection mode in Silverlight's system.windows.controls.DataGrid class?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Note I'm referring to the Grid class, not the DataGrid. By default each cell has a selection when I click on the grid. I would like the entire row to be highlighted. How can this be done? I can't seem to find a property for it and it seems like a pretty fundamental concept.

EDIT: Mistake on my part, it is in fact the DataGrid.

Comment: as with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346877/how-do-you-enable-sorting-on-a-silverlight-datagrid-that-has-grouping , I think you again mean DataGrid. Grid doesn't work like that.

Comment: Well no in this case I'm using a grid. Are you saying it's not possible to set row selection mode in a regular System.Windows.Controls.Grid?

Comment: Remember what I said in the other question? A Grid isn't for selecting data and manipulating it, it's more for the presentation of organized data, similar to a `<TABLE>` tag in HTML. You know this particularly because it derives from Panel

Comment: Ok, I take your point. But that's not something I can change. I have a grid, it has columns, and rows, and therefore cells. It has a selection model, when I click a cell, it gets highlighted. Whether it's the best approach or not, clearly they intended for selection, else it would do nothing. So I ask, is there a way to set row level selection?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you can't select a row in a panel. It's not a matter of of being the best approach, you're trying to get the Grid to do something it simply will not be able to do. You need a Control, not a Panel.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that despite it allowing you to select a cell, we're completely certain that it can't be set to select a row? I mean that is just bizarre to me, but OK.

Comment: @987S Perhaps you can post the XAML of your Grid? Christopher is correct that a WPF `<Grid>` is simply a Panel for laying out controls, like a HTML Table. It doesn't include Selection behavior.

Comment: @987S Allowing you to select a cell? are you absolutely SURE you're not talking about a DataGrid? :) Grid doesn't allow you to select a cell.

Comment: Turns out I am very wrong. I don't think I understood that you were emphatic about it not letting you select *any* cells. It was nested inside a regular Grid, which was highly confusing.

Comment: Ok so now that we've cleared up it's a DataGrid, nobody wants to tell the world how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid class does not have a concept of cells.  Its just a Panel that arranges its children in rows and columns.  Only one control in the panel can have (keyboard) focus.  You can not have multiple controls have focus.

A datagrid will actually dynamically generate and render UI elements (borders) for rows and cells, giving it the ability to display row focused/selected states.  (Ususally though VisualStates).  The Grid panel is much more lightweight -- it only renders the content you place inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Chris,  He is dreaming DataGrid.
Grid is Layout control and can not represent any collection.
You got to start learning Silverlight now...

Comment: That is precisely what I'm doing, thanks for your constructive help.